# How to reduce the Cognitive Complexity of this code based on Thomas J. McCabe’s Cyclomatic Complexity

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know there are if, then, else and switch.

But the code below is a mixture of if, then else, else if, else.

```
@HostListener('document:keydown', ['$event'])
onKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
  let index = 0;
  if (this.selectedItemIndex === null || this.selectedItemIndex < 0) {
    this.changeAria.emit('showall');
  } else {
    if ((event.key === 'ArrowDown' || event.key === 'Down') && this.isFocused) {
      index = this.selectedItemIndex;
      this.inputRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('aria-activedescendant');

      if (index >= 0 && index <= this.filteredItems.length - 1) {
        this.inputRef.nativeElement.value = this.filteredItems[index];
      }
    } else if ((event.key === 'ArrowUp' || event.key === 'Up') && this.isFocused) {
      index = this.selectedItemIndex - 2;
      this.inputRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('aria-activedescendant');
      if (index >= 0 && index <= this.filteredItems.length - 1) {
        this.inputRef.nativeElement.value = this.filteredItems[index];
      }
    } else if (index !== null && index >= 0) {
      this.changeAria.emit(this.filteredItems[index]);
    }
  }
  if (event.key === 'Enter' && this.isFocused && this.selectedItemIndex > 0) {
    if (this.selectedItemIndex === 0) {
      event.preventDefault();
      const item = (this.filter !== undefined && this.filter !== null && this.filter !== '') ? this.filter : '';
      this.onItemSelect(null, item);
    } else if (this.selectedItemIndex > 0) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.onItemSelect(null, this.filteredItems[this.selectedItemIndex - 1]);
    }
  } else if ((event.key === 'ArrowUp' || event.key === 'Up') && this.isFocused) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.selectedItemIndex === null || this.selectedItemIndex === 0) {
      this.selectedItemIndex = this.filteredItems.length;
    } else {
      if (this.selectedItemIndex > 0) {
        this.selectedItemIndex--;
      }
    }
  } else if ((event.key === 'ArrowDown' || event.key === 'Down') && this.isFocused) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (this.selectedItemIndex === null) {
      this.selectedItemIndex = 0;
    } else {
      if (this.selectedItemIndex >= 0 && this.selectedItemIndex < this.filteredItems.length) {
        this.selectedItemIndex++;
      } else {
        this.selectedItemIndex = 0;
      }
    }
  } else if ((event.keyCode == 27) && this.isFocused) {
    this.clearFocus();
    this.inputRef.nativeElement.focus();
  }
}
```

I know this can be reduced.

I want to reduce this to the lowest common denominator making this block of code much easier to read and more optimized.

UPDATE: here's my reduction of code

```
  /**
   * @name: checkForSelected
   * @description: Checks for Selected Index
   * @argument: NONE
   * @returns: boolean - meaning: there's no selected index found
   */
  checkForSelected(): boolean {
    if (this.selectedItemIndex === null || this.selectedItemIndex < 0) {
      this.hasNothingSelected = false;
    }
    return this.hasNothingSelected;
  }

  /**
   * @name: checkForArrowDnUp
   * @description: Checks for Arrow is up or down and has focused
   * @param event as ANY
   * @returns: boolean - meaning, whether the arrow is up or down 'and' focused
   */
  checkForArrowDnUp(event: KeyboardEvent): boolean {
    if ((event.key === 'ArrowDown' || event.key === 'Down') && this.isFocused) {
      this.arrowDnKeyDn = true;
    } else if ((event.key === 'ArrowUp' || event.key === 'Up') && this.isFocused) {
      this.arrowDnKeyDn = false;
    }
    return this.arrowDnKeyDn;
  }

  /**
   * @name: checkForNullOrZero
   * @description: Checks for index being NULL or ZERO
   * @param index
   * @returns: boolean - Meaning, yes index is null OR Zero or greater than ZERO
   */
  checkForNullOrZero(index: number): boolean {

    this.isNdxNullOrZero = false;

    if (index !== null && index >= 0) {
      this.isNdxNullOrZero = true;
    }

    return this.isNdxNullOrZero;
  }

  /**
   * @name: checkForEnterKeyUpDn
   * @description: Checks for keyboard event if the user PRESSES the ENTER KEY
   * @param event
   * @returns: boolean - Meaning, YES the user has indeed pressed the ENTER KEY
   * @default: variable DEFAULTS to FALSE
   */
  checkForEnterKeyUpDn(event: KeyboardEvent): boolean {

    this.isEnterKeyUpDn = false;

    if (event.key === 'Enter' && this.isFocused && this.selectedItemIndex > 0) {
      this.isEnterKeyUpDn = true;
    }
    return this.isEnterKeyUpDn;
  }

  /**
   * @name: checkForSelectedItemIndexFiltered
   * @description: Checks if the selected item has been filtered to a specific item index or not
   * @param: NONE
   * @returns: boolean - Meaning, YES the selected item has indeed been filter
   * @default: variable DEFAULTS to FALSE
   */
  checkForSelectedItemIndexFiltered(): boolean {

    this.isSelectedItemNdxFoundFiltered = false;

    if (this.selectedItemIndex >= 0 && this.selectedItemIndex < this.filteredItems.length) {
      this.selectedItemIndex++;
    } else {
      this.selectedItemIndex = 0;
    }
    return this.isSelectedItemNdxFoundFiltered;
  }


  checkForKeyEscape(event: KeyboardEvent): boolean {
    this.isKeyDnUpEscape = false;
    if ((event.key === 'Escape') && this.isFocused) {
      this.isKeyDnUpEscape = true;
    }
    return this.isKeyDnUpEscape;
  }

  onKeydown(event: KeyboardEvent) {

    const item = (this.filter !== undefined && this.filter !== null && this.filter !== '') ? this.filter : '';
    let index = 0;
    let nothingSelected = this.checkForSelected;
    let enterKeyUpDn = this.checkForEnterKeyUpDn(event);
    let arrowDnKeyUpDn = this.checkForArrowDnUp(event);
    let indexNullOrZero = this.checkForNullOrZero(index);
    let selectedItemNdxFiltered = this.checkForSelectedItemIndexFiltered();
    let keyIsEscape = this.checkForKeyEscape(event);

    if (nothingSelected) {
      this.changeAria.emit('showall');
    } else {
      if (arrowDnKeyUpDn) {
        index = this.selectedItemIndex;
        this.inputRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('aria-activedescendant');
        if (index >= 0 && index <= this.filteredItems.length - 1) {
          this.inputRef.nativeElement.value = this.filteredItems[index];
        }
      } else if (!arrowDnKeyUpDn) {
        index = this.selectedItemIndex - 2;
        this.inputRef.nativeElement.getAttribute('aria-activedescendant');
        if (index >= 0 && index <= this.filteredItems.length - 1) {
          this.inputRef.nativeElement.value = this.filteredItems[index];
        }
      } else if (indexNullOrZero) {
        this.changeAria.emit(this.filteredItems[index]);
      }
    }

    if (enterKeyUpDn) {
      event.preventDefault();

      this.enterKeyUpDown(item);

      // switch(true) {
      //   case this.selectedItemIndex === 0:
      //     this.onItemSelect(null, item);
      //     break;
      //   case this.selectedItemIndex > 0:
      //     this.onItemSelect(null, this.filteredItems[this.selectedItemIndex - 1]);
      //     break;
      //   default:
      //     false;
      //     break;
      // }

      // if (this.selectedItemIndex === 0) {
      //   this.onItemSelect(null, item);
      // } else if (this.selectedItemIndex > 0) {
      //   this.onItemSelect(null, this.filteredItems[this.selectedItemIndex - 1]);
      // }
    } else if (arrowDnKeyUpDn) {
      event.preventDefault();

      this.arrowDownKeyUpDown();

      // switch(true) {
      //   case this.selectedItemIndex === null || this.selectedItemIndex === 0:
      //     this.selectedItemIndex = this.filteredItems.length;
      //     break;
      //   default:
      //     if (this.selectedItemIndex > 0) {
      //       this.selectedItemIndex--;
      //     }
      //     false;
      //     break;
      // }

      // if (this.selectedItemIndex === null || this.selectedItemIndex === 0) {
      //   this.selectedItemIndex = this.filteredItems.length;
      // } else {
      //   if (this.selectedItemIndex > 0) {
      //     this.selectedItemIndex--;
      //   }
      // }
    } else if (!arrowDnKeyUpDn) {
      event.preventDefault();

      this.notArrowDownKeyUpDown(selectedItemNdxFiltered);

      // switch(true) {
      //   case this.selectedItemIndex === null:
      //     this.selectedItemIndex = 0;
      //     break;
      //   default:
      //     if (selectedItemNdxFiltered) {
      //       this.selectedItemIndex++;
      //     } else {
      //       this.selectedItemIndex = 0;
      //     }
      //     false;
      //     break;
      // }

      // if (this.selectedItemIndex === null) {
      //   this.selectedItemIndex = 0;
      // } else {
      //   if (selectedItemNdxFiltered) {
      //     this.selectedItemIndex++;
      //   } else {
      //     this.selectedItemIndex = 0;
      //   }
      // }
    } else if (keyIsEscape) {
      this.clearFocus();
      this.inputRef.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }

  enterKeyUpDown(item: string): void {
    switch(true) {
      case this.selectedItemIndex === 0:
        this.onItemSelect(null, item);
        break;
      case this.selectedItemIndex > 0:
        this.onItemSelect(null, this.filteredItems[this.selectedItemIndex - 1]);
        break;
      default:
        false;
        break;
    }
  }

  arrowDownKeyUpDown() {
    switch(true) {
      case this.selectedItemIndex === null || this.selectedItemIndex === 0:
        this.selectedItemIndex = this.filteredItems.length;
        break;
      default:
        if (this.selectedItemIndex > 0) {
          this.selectedItemIndex--;
        }
        false;
        break;
    }
  }

  notArrowDownKeyUpDown(selectedItemNdxFiltered: boolean) {
    switch(true) {
      case this.selectedItemIndex === null:
        this.selectedItemIndex = 0;
        break;
      default:
        if (selectedItemNdxFiltered) {
          this.selectedItemIndex++;
        } else {
          this.selectedItemIndex = 0;
        }
        false;
        break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: To make code more readable, a good 1st step is to assign names to your conditions. For example: `this.selectedItemIndex === null || this.selectedItemIndex < 0` might become `hasNothingSelected` a better name might include context for what `this` is. A good 2nd step would be to notice that most if-statements contain `this.isFocused` so pull that up into its own if-statement. Identify the parts that take you more than 2s to figure out what they're doing and make them more readable. Code is for people, not computers. First write clear readable code, then optimize.

Comment: Shelby, thank you. Let me implement and get back to you. Secondly, off topic, I'm a member of StackOverflow and I don't see how to sign in here with my SO login. What am I missing?

Comment: Login is generally shared between the Stack Exchange sites to my knowledge. Try logging into Stack Overflow and clicking the upper-right most button. There should be a list of communities you can edit, then add Code Review?

Comment: YAY! Thank you, Shelby